# jquery don't change the attributes of a tag

Tags: jquery

my code is like below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js">/script>
    </head>
    <body>
         <p id="test1">This is a paragraph.</p>
         <button id="btn1">Set Text</button>
     </body>
 </html>
```

and my jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn1").click(function(){
        $("#test1").text("Hello world!");
        $("#test1").attr('background-color','#F00');
    });
});
```

It changes the text but doesn't change the color. what's wrong with my code? 
jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/m6AnK/2/

Comment: Use `css` to change the style properties `$("#test1").css('background-color','#F00');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not an attribute, it's a style ?

change

```
$("#test1").attr('background-color','#F00');
```

to

```
$("#test1").css('background-color','#F00');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `CSS` , instead of `ATTR`

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#btn1").click(function(){
        $("#test1").text("Hello world!");
       $("#test1").css('background-color','red');
      });


    });
```

Answer (score 0):

**Replace**

```
$("#test1").attr('background-color','#F00');
```

**With**

```
$("#test1").css('background-color','#F00');
```

Comment: replace Repalce with Replace